# D200 - bracketing - number of frames

Tags: nikon, camera-settings, bracketing

I can't control the number of shots anymore.
Rotating the backpanel dial controls bracketing "on" and "off" (showing symbol only), not the number of shots (which it used to do).

How can I get the control back?

Guy

Answer (score 2):

The relevant details appear to be on page 167 of [your manual](http://cdn-10.nikon-cdn.com/pdf/manuals/dslr/D200_en.pdf) under the custom bracketing settings.  You can set the parameters to either be set manually or automatically, it sounds like they must have been changed to automatic from manual.